# Auto subscribe roster presence request in ejabberd by server

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am new in ejabberd world. Currently i am using ejabberd server for instant messaging.

### My usecase

When client send roster subscription to the server then server **automatically approve subscription requests on the contact's behalf** if exist.

**Ejabberd does not have this feature or option to automatically approve subscription requests**

for this i am using these hooks

```
roster_in_subscription
roster_out_subscription
```

My problem is how to accept subscription request after getting request.

Is there any alternate solution?

plz help

Answer (score 1):

This is what is mentioned in RFC 3921 present [here](https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#presence) in presence section.

Visit section 5.1.6. Responsibility to auto-accept presence requests lies with the client.

I wrote the following code in smack to auto-accept presence requests.

```
Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
```